# OnKey no funciona con las teclas del movil

Tags: android, edittext

Tengo este codigo:

```
  nuevo.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {

                String articulo;

                articulo = nuevo.getText().toString();
                listas.add(new ListasSecundarias(articulo));

                if (listas.isEmpty())
                {
                    adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
                }
                adapter.notifyItemInserted(listas.size()+1);

                guardar(articulo,NombreDeLaLista);
                nuevo.setText("");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

y lo que pasa es que si presiono enter con el teclado del pc realiza las acciones correspondidas, pero cuando presiono con enter en la tecla del móvil no pasa nada.

Comment: Hola bienvenido, ¿dejame ver si entendí tu lo que quieres es hacer como un buscador?

Comment: Hola, gracias, no mira, lo que tengo es un editText el cual al hacer click en la tecla enter del teclado del movil, deberia de guardar lo que esta en el EditText y guardarlo en una tabla sqlite y agregarlo a un recyclerview. Principalmente al dar click en la tecla enter del movil, deberia agregar el contenidio del EdiText a la lista

Answer (score -1):

El onKey solo se usa para detectar eventos del hardware , mas info aquí [onKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html#onKey(android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent))

Si deseas detectar el enter o 'done' de tu teclado virtual, lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente

A tu EditText en tu xml, dale la opción de `actionDone` en `imeOptions`:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edittext_done"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    />
```

Luego en tu código agrega lo siguiente:

```
nuevo.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
       //aquí tu lógica ...

       return true;
    }
    return false;
    } 
});
```

Nota: Trata de habilitar el teclado virtual de tu simulador

Comment: agregar android:imeOptions="actionDone"  no ayudaría a detectar lo que desea el OP. Además ¿como puede detectar "Enter"?, ¿has probado este código?

Comment: **El método onEditorAction es para un TextView no un EditText**  ver más : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html

Comment: plop, pero si el edittext extiende de textview :/   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Comment: Te sugiero trates de probar el código que comentas, simplemente no compilará...

Comment: actualizado :) , gracias